# Blocking specific part of a website OS-wide?

Tags: windows, browser, blocking

I have read through tons questions asking the same thing, but all of those questions and solutions involve either a proxy, a 3rd-party program, or a browser extension. This is not a duplicate of any of those that I found -- a proxy, 3rd-party program, or a browser extension will not suffice for this question. Please make sure if you are marking this as a duplicate that the question has the same constraints as this one.

Without using a proxy, a 3rd-party program, or a browser extension, how can I block a specific page of a website (i.e. www.website.com/page) and any subpage of that (www.website.com/page/etc)?

This is a personal Windows 10 computer, and I have full administrative privileges. I do not have access to my router. A program I use has a web-browser built in that is quicker to use for small tasks than opening a website up in my preferred browser. Unfortunately I can't use extensions since it isn't a traditional browser. I could use a proxy, and I could use a 3rd-party program like Fiddler, but I don't like the idea of continuously running either of those for something so small. Editing the hosts file probably would have done the trick, but it can only block domains -- not parts of them (AFAIK).

Comment: dosen't seem possible simply because most OSes arn't aware of websites natively - its a higher level than OSes need to bother about. It dosen't seem possible.

Comment: With your restrictions it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I still think a proxy is your best bet. You can install and operate one locally on your machine. Since you have full admin, this is in fact an option. I suggest you take a look at the Squid proxy. Here's a Windows installation guide for it: http://docs.diladele.com/tutorials/installing_squid_windows/index.html

Comment: In the question I specifically clarified that I did not want to use a proxy.

Comment: Yes, I see that. If you want to do this within any kind of practicality, then you have to use a proxy and have rules that follow your demands. I thought maybe you didn't know you could run a local proxy server on your machine for this. The only other way I can think of is if you write your own virtual network driver and bridge it some how. I think that'd be much much more work though.